# Send csv file to mySql database every 2 mins?

Tags: php, mysql, batch-file, csv

---

I'm generating a new csv file (approx) every 2 mins on my machine through a local application that I've written, and I need this file to update my database each time it is generated. I've successfully done this locally via a (scheduled) repeating bat file, and now I need to move this process online so my website has access to this data in as similar of a time-frame as possible.

I'm totally green on mySql and learning it as I go, so I was wondering if there is anything I should be concerned about or any best practices I should follow for this task.

Can I connect directly to my server-side database from my cmd window (bat file) and send this data once the process has run and generated the csv file? Or do I need to upload this file via ftp/php to my webserver and import it into the database once it is online?

Any help/thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could possibly use the MySQL command-line client to execute a `LOAD DATA INFILE` query. If you use the `LOCAL` option it will transfer the CSV file to the server for you. You should be able to do that in a batch file. The MySQL reference is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html)

Comment: Yup, I haven't tried scheduling it in my bat file yet, but initial test through the cmd window do seem to be working, so I'm sure it'll be fine. Thank you sir!